# play second video while first video is reached to half

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video-player

I need some code or login using which I can solve my issue.
I can design HTML5 video player but issue is plying second Ad video. What I need is:
User will click on any video from listing. HTML5 video player will start playing it. When user will reach at middle of the video, That first video will be pause and Second Ad video will start playing. And once ad video will be completed, Player will keep continue with first video.

It must work with safari.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the middle of the video by currentTime and duration of HTML property.
And you can pause video by pause function and play ad video by using another video DOM.

```
var delta = 0.05;
setInterval(function(){
  if(video.currentTime >= video.duration*(0.5-delta)
    && video.currentTime <= video.duration*(0.5+delta)) {
    video.pause(); //pause current video

    //play ad and resume video when ad end        
  }
}, 1000);
```